# how can I validate multiple ng-repeated ng-form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable form list and want to display validation error messages outside of the list elements.

consider this template:

```
<form name="gForm">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="invoice in invoices" ng-form="invoiceForm">
            <td><input name="amount" type="number" max="200" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div ng-show="gForm.invoiceForm.amount.$invalid">you must the money</div>
    <button ng-click="addInvoice()">add invoice</button>
</form>
```

the validation error would only be displayed when the last ng-repeat is invalid. Put another way, `gForm.invoiceForm` points to the lastly created form in ng-repeat.

I've seen other questions related to this problem but they only suggest repeating the validation messages inside the ng-repeat. I need the message to be outside and displayed once only.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, `gForm.invoiceForm` does refer to the last `<tr>` in ng-repeat.
If you want to display the error when any of the amounts is invalid, you can use `gForm.$invalid`. In fact there is no need to use `ng-form="invoiceForm"` unless there are more requirements not evident from the current question's code.

Another problem is that, in order for Angular to recognize the input and apply its directive (and its magic consequently), **[the `ng-model` directive is required](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)** as well.

Adding the `ng-model` directive and changing the condition to `gForm.$invalid` solves the problem:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="invoice in invoices">
    <td><input name="amount" type="number" max="200"
               ng-model="invoice.amount" /></td>
</tr>
...
<div ng-show="gForm.$invalid">you must the money</div>
...
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/43KM7/)**.

Comment: your example does only validate the last `<tr>`

Comment: It does when I try it. What do you mean it doesn't ? What happens when you try it (and what is the expected behaviour) ?

Comment: whatever I input in the first two fields (an empty string or "fsgfdgs" for example), the validation does not trigger.

Comment: Exactly ! Because it only validates the last `<tr>` (and neither of the first two is the last). Is it not what you wanted ?

Comment: no, what I want is: if any of the fields is invalid, then the invalidity message must be displayed

Comment: Sorry, I missundestood your requirements. Please, take a llok at my updated answer.

Comment: @BiAiB: Did you take a look at my updated answer (and demo) ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: sorry to answer that late. I check your demo and it does the job right, at least at first sight. In the meantime, I've made my own solution which is more complicated. So I'll check if your solution works in my case.

Comment: @BiAiB: If you feel this answer solves the problem (as stated in your question), please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? Yes you need to use ng-model, but also you need a unique name:

```
<div ng-app="pageModule"
        ng-controller="parentCtrl">
        <form name="gForm">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="invoice in invoices" ng-form="invoiceForm">
                    <td>{{invoice.name}}: <input name="invoice.name" required type="number" max="200" ng-model="invoice.amount" /></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div ng-show="gForm.$invalid && showError">you must the money</div>
            <button ng-click="addInvoice()">add invoice</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>

var pageModule = angular.module('pageModule',[])
.controller('parentCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.invoices = [
        { name : 'ford' },
        { name : 'chevy' },
        { name : 'honda' },
    ]
    $scope.showError = false;
    $scope.addInvoice = function() {
        $scope.showError = true;
        console.log('add invoice');
    }
})
    </script>
```